# Change Django form fields widget attributes without having to do every field separately?

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I set a class to all of these fields?

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-lg'
    self.fields['email'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-lg'
    self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-lg'
    self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-lg'
```

It do not look good. How can I change the fields for all without having to type for each field separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for field in self.fields:
    field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control input-lg'
```